# Table exists in show tables but doesn't exist when I try to select from it

Tags: mysql, sql, file-permissions, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite and I needed to reinstall mysql, I have reinstalled it using `brew install mysql` but before I did this I backed up the data folder. (I usually do this since it's faster than exporting and importing :) and it usually works).

The problem is after the reinstall, after I copied back the data folder, I have all my Databases, all my tables but I have a peculiar problem.

And that problem is:

```
mysql> use eek
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_eek        |
+----------------------+
| e_commentmeta        |
| e_comments           |
| e_links              |
| e_options            |
| e_postmeta           |
| e_posts              |
| e_term_relationships |
| e_term_taxonomy      |
| e_terms              |
| e_usermeta           |
| e_users              |
+----------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `e_links`;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'eek.e_links' doesn't exist
```

I haven't got any results in searching for this problem, most of them where problems made of other reasons (like naming tables with . in it's name)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was from the fact that when I copied the databases from the data folder, I only copied each individual folder and missed the `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1` & `ibdata1`.